# Expression has no effect warning

Tags: c

I have a callback function which gets called when a hardware interrupt is generated. But when I build my code I am getting "expression has no effect"

```
void registerCallBack(int originator,uint32* cbackFunction)
{
    Originator[originator].callback = cbackFunction;
}

// interrupt calls the following function
void callbackFunction(int originator)
{

    Originator[originator].callback;  // throwing warning here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Call the function

```
void callbackFunction(int originator)
{

    Originator[originator].callback();  //parenthesis
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it simply be

```
Originator[originator].callback();
```

so that the callback is actually invoked?

Answer (score 1):

You generally need make function calls with () at the end. :)

```
   Originator[originator].callback();
```